# How to toggle between tabs in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: python, java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, rest-assured

How to toggle between tabs in IntelliJ IDEA?

I wanted to toggle between tabs in IntelliJ IDEA as I have multiple files and working on them sometimes requires switching from one tab to another (or one file to another) thus I wanted to know any shortcut to do that. If anyone has the solution please do let me know.